# uiwebview wrapping long words

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I realized, that when I have words longer then one line, it will not be wrapped in  a uiwebview. It shows scrollbars at the bottom to move the webview.
Is there any option to force wrapping of long words ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the word-wrap:break-word CSS to force long words to be broken.  For example,

```
.breakit {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

However, you may need to explicitly set the width of the container.  Here's a in-code example:

```
NSString *wordwrapstyle = @"";
if (forceWordWrap){
    wordwrapstyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"style=\"width:%f;word-wrap:break-word;\"", self.frame.size.width];
}

[ms appendFormat:@"<p %@>%@</p>", wordwrapstyle, text];
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much. That helped a lot. And I learned something :-)